# Stop Teamcity showing deleted branches

Tags: git, configuration, teamcity

We're using TeamCity, and I've set up jobs to pull from branches. But when those branches are deleted they still appear in Teamcity:

[image: List of outdated branches, only refs/master is active]

*(List of outdated branches, but only `refs/master` is actually active)*

The [Teamcity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-Activebranches) actually specifies what constitutes an active branch:

> ## Active branches
>
> In a build configuration with configured branches, the
>   Overview page shows active branches.
>
> A number of parameters define whether a branch is active. The
>   parameters can be changed either in a build configuration (this will
>   affect one build configuration only), project, or in the internal
>   properties (this defines defaults for the entire server). A parameter
>   in the configuration overrides a parameter in the internal properties.
>
> A branch is considered active if:
>
> - it is present in the VCS repository and has recent commits (i.e.
>     commits with the age less than the value of
>     `teamcity.activeVcsBranch.age.days` parameter, 7 days by default).
> - or it has recent builds (i.e. builds with the age less than the value of
>     `teamcity.activeBuildBranch.age.hours` parameter, 24 hours by default).
> - ! A closed VCS branch with builds will still be displayed as active
>     during 24 hours after last build. To remove closed branches from
>     display, set `teamcity.activeBuildBranch.age.hours=0`.

But... I don't understand their description! :) What do they mean with "parameters in the configuration"? I've tried making parameters in my jobs like so:

[image: Adding parameter teamcity.activeBuildBranch.age.hours]

*(Adding parameter `teamcity.activeBuildBranch.age.hours`)*

But that doesn't do anything. Maybe I'm exposing myself as a total TC noob, but can anyone guide me through how to correctly alter these settings so I only show repository-active branches in my build jobs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suddenly had success after adding parameters to the *project* configuration. Before now I've been adding parameters to individual builds and never saw a difference.. Maybe that's just me misunderstanding the obvious.

[image]

[image]

```
teamcity.activeBuildBranch.age.hours = 0
teamcity.activeVcsBranch.age.days = 1
```

This works in-so-far as the list of active branches is culled. There's still one deleted branch it considers active for reasons I can't yet decipher (history was rewritten several times in it), but at least all others are now inactive.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar question when we first started using  branches  in TC.

As I recall the branches will stay visible until the conditions specified expire. It doesn't matter if the branch has been deleted, if it had commits in the last 7 days then it will stay visible for 7 days after the last commit even if it is deleted immediately.

So basically don't worry, they disappear eventually and I think you can lower the `teamcity.activeVcsBranch.age.days` value if 7 days is too long to wait, but you will then lose branches that have no activity within that time I think.

Comment: I'd like to experiment with lowered values, to see if it suits my expectations better. Can you explain how the `teamcity.activeVcsBranch.age.days` parameter is altered?

The documentation suggests this can be done, I just can't figure out how to implement it.